# How to handle DateTime values from database in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a weird situation in handling  DateTime data in my C# application and need to refactor my code properly. The code is as follows:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(); 
DateTime end = new DateTime();
String inDate = "";
String outDate = "";
String inTime = "";
String outTime = ""; 


inDate = DataObject.InDate();
outDate = DataObject.OutDate();
inTime = DataObject.InTime();
outTime = DataObject.OutTime();

//I have check for null as the database may return null values
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inDate) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(inTime))
    {
          scheduleStart = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(inDate).ToShortDateString() + " " + clockInTime);
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outDate) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(outTime))
    {
          scheduleEnd = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToDateTime(outDate).ToShortDateString() + " " + outTime);
    }
    if (start != null && end != null)
    {
          TimeSpan span = end.Subtract(start);
    }
```

This line, `if (start != null && end != null)`, complains that it will always be true. I thought of removing the initialization of the `scheduleStart` and `end` variables. Now, `if (start != null && end != null)` line complains of usage of uninitialized variables. I thought of using `DateTime?` for both `start` and `end` variables. Now, the error I get is that, `DateTime?` doesn't have a definition for `Subtract()`. Unfortunately I have to use this method. So, what will be the best way to resolve this issue and refactor this code?

Comment: 1) Do not store `DateTime` types as string/varchar, store them as `DateTime` types in the database as well. Every database provider I have ever heard of has a way to store `DateTime` types. There is a good reason that type systems exist, use the appropriate types for your data when you can. 2) If the value is not required make the column definition nullable. The reason the above evals to true is because DateTime is a struct and cannot be null. By making the column nullable you can now use `DateTime?`.

Comment: `DateTime` isn't a nullable type so can't have a value of null. Use `DateTime?` if you want to be able to assign a null value.

Comment: `DateTime` is a value type it doesn't directly support `null`, you'd need to use nullable `DateTime?` for that.

Comment: If you know a nullable value is not null, you can use the .Value property to get a plain DateTime where you can use Subtract

Comment: read up on using nullable types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime?` for the start and end, and then use `.Value` when you know they are not `null`:

```
DateTime? scheduleStart = null;
DateTime? scheduleEnd = null;


    if (scheduleStart != null && scheduleEnd != null)
    {
          TimeSpan span = scheduleEnd.Value.Subtract(scheduleStart.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`scheduleStart.Value.Subtract` does exist. Or you can just cast to`DateTime` if you've done the `null` check anyway.